# Iterating through a list and drawing a colored square

Tags: java, arrays, list, colors, awt

I have a colored box, I want it to change color every 1/2 second, however I want my code to run as well.

I'm using Java AWT's Graphic Api to draw using g.fillRect(568, 383, 48, 48); where g is wrapped to 'Graphics.'

So you'd think that its simple right?

```
Color[] colors

colors = new Color[4];

colors[0] = new Color(Color.red);
colors[1] = new Color(Color.blue);
colors[2] = new Color(Color.green);
colors[3] = new Color(Color.yellow);

for(int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++){
    g.setColor(colors[i]);
    g.fillRect(568, 383, 48, 48);
}
```

This is all cool but the problem is that none of my program runs when this for loop is running...

I think I can make the game 'Multi-Threaded' which means it can do more than one thing at a time but I have no idea how to do this and it sounds hard, all help appreciated!

Comment: You will **have** to make it multi threaded if you want more then 1 thing to happen at the time. Look for example at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm for a simple example of threading.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen Or use a Swing Timer, which makes it safer to update the Ui from within as it won't violate the singe threaded nature of the Swing API

Answer (score 2):

Most UI frameworks aren't thread safe, so you need to beware of that.  For example, in Swing, you could use a Swing `Timer` to act as a pseudo loop.  Because the `Timer` notifies the `ActionListener` from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, it makes it safe to update the UI or the state of the UI from within, without risking thread race conditions

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

[image: Colors]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class JavaApplication430 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JavaApplication430();
    }

    public JavaApplication430() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Color[] colors;
        private int whichColor = 0;

        public TestPane() {

            colors = new Color[4];

            colors[0] = Color.red;
            colors[1] = Color.blue;
            colors[2] = Color.green;
            colors[3] = Color.yellow;

            Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    whichColor++;
                    repaint();
                    if (whichColor >= colors.length) {
                        whichColor = colors.length - 1;
                        ((Timer)(e.getSource())).stop();
                    }
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(colors[whichColor]);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot imagine how you could create an interactive game if your code is single thread. To change the box color periodically you will have to put your thread to sleep. If your game is not multi-thread, then this will freeze your application, preventing user interaction. You will find a lot of interesting materials about programming with threads in Java:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-thread/

http://moderntone.blogspot.com.br/2013/02/a-simple-java-multithreading-example.html

Just google it!